# Ungrouped files of the report or form in the project tree when adding an existing files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012.

I heed to move some common files from one project to another.
I remember under VS2008 it was working fine.. so the designer and the code behind files in that case were groupped in the project tree correctly.
But in 2012 it works wrong.. pls, see the pics.
Black frame is he correct groupped files of the created inside the project files.

In red - moved and imported.
You can seethe triangles (tree knot) 2 in red and 1 in black. 
Designer and code behind.. But should be one knot for both of them.
This is bad, because I'm unable load the layouts in the Constructor..
How to treat this? Please, any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try pressing the refresh button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `Visual Studio` cannot resolve the dependency by itself.

One workaround to solve this is by opening your `csproj` file and add `DependentUpon` on both the `designer.cs` and the `resource` (`.resx`) files of your `Control` in their `Compile` and `EmbeddedResource`.

Here is one example, suppose your `Control` name is `Form1` and is a `Form`. When the dependency is wrong and the items are not knotted, you would see this:

```html
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx" />
```

Change that into:

```html
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

And the Visual Studio would display your `Control` dependency correctly.

---

By [Vitali Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834850/vitali-petrov): One thing I'd like to highlight for others - in `DependentUpon` tags the directory name in `filename` should be skipped.

```html
    <Compile Include="Panels\DataPanel.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Panels\DataPanel.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DataPanel.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Panels\DataPanel.resx">
      <DependentUpon>DataPanel.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm curious to know why VS can't figure this out on its own, if anyone knows.

Comment: @StarfleetSecurity because the dependency is a kind of "directives" actually. Though the names of the files are the same (example: `abc.cs`, `abc.designer.cs`, `abc.resx`), there is no guarantee that they are actually depending on each other. You may think of it like a macro in C - It is like a pre-code, not the code itself. If I am not mistaken, later VS may probably do that (combining the items) when you copy-paste from a project to project by looking at the dependencies direction in the project file.